# Oracle SQL - Fetch all rows if one among multiple columns not null

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to check OR condition between multiple columns.

```
select * from tableA where (COL1 or Col2) is not null
```

how to fetch this?

My actual query is something like :

```
select b.empname,b.hours,b.minutes from table1 a,table2 b
where a.pk_id=b.fk_id and a.type='UT'
and a.SOME_NUMBER='123' and b.hours is not null or b.minutes is not null;
```

but

> b.hours is not null or b.minutes is not null;

is fetching repeated records

Comment: c1 is not null or c2 is not null, or perhaps coalesce(c1,c2) is not null (depending on data types.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.empname,b.hours,b.minutes from table1 a,table2 b
where a.pk_id=b.fk_id and a.type='UT'
and a.SOME_NUMBER='123' and COALESCE(b.hours,b.minutes) is not null;
```

worked fine for me.

Thanks everyone for the input

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
   select * from tableA where COL1 is not null or Col2 is not null
```

Comment: Why not use `COALESCE(COL1, Col2) IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, maybe not matching data types?

Comment: Hmmm...could we safely cast the two columns to a common nullable type and then use `COALESECE` ?

Comment: I would have answered that way if the OP specified the data types of COL1 and  Col2

Comment: where COL1 is not null or Col2 is not null is causing data repetition

Answer (score 0):

Its just `select * from tableA where COL1 IS NOT NULL or Col2 IS NOT NULL`.